# Can't Update Array Data In Laravel

Tags: laravel

In the table, the information field is an array, and when I try to edit the information inside this array, I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nationalCode' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `kycs` where ((`nationalCode` = 1234567891 and `state` = tehran and `city` = tehran and `address` = example address and `zipcode` = 9477143812)) limit 1)
```

this is my code :

```
        if ($kyc = auth()->user()->kyc()->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->first()) {
            //   $data = Kyc::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
            if ($kyc->selfie['status'] == 'rejected') {
                $this->validate(
                    [
                        'nationalCode' => 'required|nationalcode',
                        'state' => 'required',
                        'city' => 'required',
                        'address' => 'required',
                        'zipcode' => 'required|zipcode',
                        'selfie' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2024',
                    ]
                );
                $selfie_url = $this->selfie->store('documents/'.Crypt::decryptString($kyc->secret));
                Kyc::updateOrCreate([
                    [
                        'information' => [
                            'nationalCode' => $this->nationalCode,
                            'state' => $this->state,
                            'city' => $this->city,
                            'address' => $this->address,
                            'zipcode' => $this->zipcode,
                        ],
                        'selfie' => [
                            'url' => Crypt::encryptString($selfie_url),
                            'status' => 'pending',
                            'last_update' => Carbon::now(),
                            'desc' => '',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]);

                return redirect()->route('frontend.auth.verification.notice');
            }
```

what is problem

Comment: Probably typo, do you havw have `nationalCode` column on `kycs` table?

Comment: @Espresso I save the nationalCode as an array in the information field

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have the nationalCode column in table migration and they are run.Can you share the MIgration for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Add your columns as log as they exist in your model:

`protected $fillable = ['nationalCode'];`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you didn't correctly mark the information and selfie columns to be casted to an array. Please check if you have similar code in your Kyc model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'information' => 'array',
    'selfie' => 'array'
];
```